# Is corruption the root cause Bangladesh is stranded in "developing nation" status?

Tags: corruption, bangladesh

Bangladesh has been stranded in "developing country" status for the last 50 years or so. Its HDI is also very low.

Is corruption the root cause this country is stranded in a "developing country" status?

Or, is it a meta-cause?

Comment: This Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Bangladesh lists several reasons for Bangladesh. I suspect that for other countries the reasons will be similar, but different. In particular, it says: "The economy faces challenges of infrastructure bottlenecks, insufficient power and gas supplies, bureaucratic corruption, natural calamities and a lack of skilled workers."

Comment: Is *"corruption"* really a reason for anything?  It seems more like a *symptom* of other things, or a means to some end, *i.e.* some domestic rascal or outside power deploys some human chess pieces to block off or control some resource.

Comment: This is really an invitation for everyone to bash Bangladesh and SE Asia with one opinion or another.  Or, if so inclined, they'll bash on the rich countries for being mean to SE Asia instead.  In fact, this can be extended to other poor countries. Thing is, looking at [wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developing_country), the whole area is "developing countries".  Pick something more specific and ask about it.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, my question is very specific.

Comment: And my answer is:  no, corruption, while present, isn't the only problem and I can give you a whole bunch of *opinions* what else is wrong with Bangladesh.  Other people will have different opinions on what else is wrong.  So your question really boils down to "what's wrong with Bangladesh?".  Well, at least this Q is not about all of SE Asia as it was when it first came out.

Comment: Do you have a source for your assertion that Bangladesh's "developing" status is at least partly due to corruption?

Comment: The whole region have so much corruption, and all countries there are developing nations. Personally I think the biggest drawback Bangladesh has is lack of good higher education. And I don't see a solution to this except with help from outside the country.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is the sum of *positive* factors, the sum of *negative* factors, and various feedback loops.

- A low elevation and flood risks from rivers hinders development. This can be overcome by well-maintained levees, but those are expensive.
- A country with few natural resources has to find other things to export. This could be cheap labor or expensive labor.
- A high population density can represent either an urban population without rural areas or an overpopulated countryside.
- A low median age can represent either a good ratio of young people to pensioners or plenty of unemployed youth looking for too few jobs.

Keep in mind that the "developed" nations don't stand still. The goal is moving and catching up is difficult.

Comment: *A low elevation and flood risks from rivers hinders development. This can be overcome by well-maintained levees, but those are expensive.* --- International donors supplied billions of dollars over the years to do exactly this. All money was eaten up by corrupt eurocrats and local government bodies.

Comment: *A country with few natural resources has to find other things to export. This could be cheap labor or expensive labor.* --- BD is one of the biggest suppliers of labor to the Gulf countries. That doesn't help much as the remittances supplied by those poor guys are embezzled by corrupt politicians.

Comment: @user366312 *All money was eaten up by corrupt eurocrats*  BS.  Bangladesh has had much less loss of life from typhoons in the past few years than it did in the past, mostly due to purpose-build shelters/elevated platforms.  I am sure there is corruption, and plenty of it, but get your facts straight before you claim none of the funds were correctly used.  https://www.economist.com/schools-brief/2020/05/30/climate-adaptation-policies-are-needed-more-than-ever

Comment: @user366312: Levees and so on don't actually work all that well.  They may prevent small floods, but turn large ones into major disasters.

Comment: @jamesqf: The Dutch would disagree. The major disaster in 1953 was due to deteriorated levees after WW2, with new levees there has been only small, contained flooding. The Netherlands are of course at low elevation and densely populated, just like Bangladesh., but at the opposite of the HDI scale. And importantly, it's also at the opposite of the corruption scale.

Comment: @MSalters, is low corruption the cause or the effect? (I believe there are muddled feedback loops which make it *both* ...)

Comment: @MSalters: Doesn't that Dutch experience prove the point?  Or we could look at the failures of New Orleans levees during hurricane Katrina.  Engineers design such things to meet reasonable expectations of flood height &c, then along comes something that exceeds those reasonable expectations.

Comment: @jamesqf Katrina does not seem a good example of this point, (as far as I understand), it did *not* exceeed reasonable expectations, the levees were known to be insufficient but neglected due to funding limitations, and for political reasons it was allowed to build significant amounts in new housing in places which were known to be at risk to flood in such an event without a corresponding construction of new levees to protect them. Engineering-wise the consequences were not surprising even if politicians got "surprised" as they chose to ignore these issues or leave them for the next guy/gal.